# Casting an object to an interface which is not implemented

Tags: java, interface, casting

I found following question in my study book and a bit confused:

Given the following code, which option, if used to replace `/* INSERT CODE
HERE */`, will enable a reference variable of type `Roamable` to refer to an object of the
`Phone` class? (Select 1 option.)

```
interface Roamable{}
class Phone {}
class Tablet extends Phone implements Roamable {
    //INSERT CODE HERE
}
```

Options are:

1. `Roamable var = new Phone();`
2. `Roamable var = (Roamable)Phone();`
3. `Roamable var = (Roamable)new Phone();`
4. Because interface `Roamable` and class `Phone` are unrelated, a reference variable
   of type `Roamable` can’t refer to an object of class `Phone`.

I thought the correct option is 4, however it says it is 3.

But, `Phone` doesn't implement `Roamable` interface, so you can't cast, can you?

Comment: Well, did you try this? What did you find out after testing?

Comment: Right.  Try it and see what happens.

Answer (score 12):

The correct answer is `3`: The compiler sees only that a `Phone` is being cast to a `Roamable` and that `Phone` is not final, so it thinks that the object being cast, although referred to as `Phone` may be a subclass of `Phone` that *does* implement `Roamable`, so no compile-time error or warning is issued.

According to [JLS chapter 5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.5)

**5.5.1. Reference Type Casting**

> Given a compile-time reference type S (source) and a compile-time reference type T (target), a casting conversion exists from S to T if no compile-time errors occur due to the following rules.
>   If T is an interface type:
>
> If S is not a final class (§8.1.1), then, if there exists a supertype X of T, and a supertype Y of S, such that both X and Y are provably distinct parameterized types, and that the erasures of X and Y are the same, a compile-time error occurs.
>
> Otherwise, the cast is always legal at compile time (because even if S does not implement T, a subclass of S might).
>
> If S is a final class (§8.1.1), then S must implement T, or a compile-time error occurs.

---

The following code compiles:

```
interface Roamable{}
class Phone {}
class Tablet extends Phone implements Roamable {
    Roamable var = (Roamable)new Phone(); // Compiles
}
```

Comment: The code compiles, but the question is `which option will enable a reference variable of type Roamable to refer to an object of the Phone class`. A variable can only refer to an object at runtime and that will not work as it will cause a ClassCastException.

Comment: @Reboot I (and the problem author it seems) took that to mean "at compile time". You are quite right though that it would explode if run.

Comment: This is a question from a study book and if it is really written like that in the book, then the answer in the book is wrong and the correct answer is 4. If it is meant like the correct answer in the book would imply then the question is badly written. In either case the book is wrong.

Comment: Yeah, I would agree that if the above is more or less an accurate depiction of the original question it is incomplete at best.

Answer (score 1):

Answer would be **4**

as

```
1 is incorrect(explanation --> 4)
2 is incorrect syntax
3 is incorrect typecast.
```

---

Note that **answer 3** is valid as long as it is just about **compilation**. When you say you have a instance of `Phone` class you can type cast into `Tablet` (Similar to you can cast `Object` to `String`). And since `Tablet` implements `Roamable` you can very well use a `Roamable` reference to refer it. `Problem will occur at runtime` as the `Object` is really of type `Phone`.

This is just one of the linkage patter(in current context) which allows successful compilation. But as Bohemian has mentioned in his answer in general

> If we are typecasting a compile time reference S(non final) to compile time reference T then compilation will be successful as `even if S does not implement T, a subclass of S might`. If S is a final class , then S must implement T, or a compile-time error occurs.

Actually there is no need of `Tablet` class extending `Phone` class at all. As long as Phone class is `not final` compilation will be successful

```
interface Roamable{}
class Phone {}
class Tablet implements Roamable {
    Roamable var = (Roamable)new Phone(); // Compiles
}
```

Comment: Just so you know, your explanation is completely wrong, and your casting example irrelevant.

Comment: You should probably familiarise yourself with the [definition of plagiarism](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/plagiarism) too :)

Comment: :) It says `without crediting the original author`. But I mentioned you in my answer and also thanked you in the comment.