# Casting an object into any interface?

Tags: java, object, interface, casting, classcastexception

I have have an interface called `MyInterface` and a class `MyClass` which is not implemented by `MyInterface`.

```
interface MyInterface {
}

class MyClass{
}
```

If I create an instance of `MyClass`, Compiler allows to cast that to `MyInterface`. I know that it will throw `ClassCastException` in runtime. But why does the compiler allow for casting?

Comment: because you told so to compiler, by using `(MyInterface)` you're explicitely saying "I know what I'm doing, cast it without questions" (actually compiler emits warnings)

Comment: interfaces don't implement classes

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21812423/438992 As with all things Java, it's in the spec.